# Google Blogger Post Box Background Transparancy?

Tags: blogger

I am starting a blog on blogger with Google. I have the whole thing ready with the exception of 1 item. With my current Blog background, I need a white background for my Posts. With that there, it is hard to see the background. I am looking for a way /CSS code? to make it so the background for each post is semi-transparent. almost like glass on a misty day.

Answer (score 0):

First give your theme name , for mine is

CSS :-

```
.post-outer {
        background-color: white;
    }
```

Theme is picture window